# How do I use Angular to dynamically update an img src

Tags: angularjs

I have a gallery of images, and I want to have them open up a "zoomable" version when clicked/tapped.

I've got everything working, other than having the zoom-image src update.

This is my code in the controller.

```
// setup array of images and preset the zoom-image
$scope.zoomPictureSrc = '';
angular.forEach($scope.trayDetails.tray_images, function(trayImage) {
    var myBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+trayImage.data;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = myBase64;
    $scope.savedPictures.push(img);
    if ($scope.zoomPictureSrc === '') {
        $scope.zoomPictureSrc = img.src;
    }
});

// set the new zoom-image src & open the divs
$scope.zoomDisplay = false;
$scope.zoomOpen = function (source) {
    $scope.zoomPictureSrc = source;
    $scope.zoomDisplay = true;
    $scope.$evalAsync();
};
// close the zoom image divs
$scope.zoomClose = function () {
    $scope.zoomDisplay = false;
};
```

and this is in my view

```
<ul class="tray-photos clearfix">
    <li ng-repeat="savedPicture in savedPictures" class="photo">
        <span class="photo-container" ng-click="zoomOpen(savedPicture.src)"><img ng-controller="TrayDetailsCtrl" ng-src="{{savedPicture.src}}" /></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="zoom-background" ng-show="zoomDisplay"></div>
<div class="zoom-wrap" ng-show="zoomDisplay">
    <div class="zoom-container">
        <span class="zoom-content photo-container" ng-click="zoomClose()"><img ng-controller="TrayDetailsCtrl" hm-pinchin="pinchIn" hm-pinchout="pinchOut" ng-src="{{zoomPictureSrc}}" /></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The zoom-xxx divs show and hide, but the img itself is not changing. I've tried the code with and without the call to $scope.$evalAsync();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the same controller twice, which creates the controller with two different scopes.  Try something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TrayDetailsCtrl">
    <ul class="tray-photos clearfix">
        <li ng-repeat="savedPicture in savedPictures" class="photo">
            <span class="photo-container" ng-click="zoomOpen(savedPicture.src)"><img ng-src="{{savedPicture.src}}" /></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="zoom-background" ng-show="zoomDisplay"></div>
    <div class="zoom-wrap" ng-show="zoomDisplay">
        <div class="zoom-container">
            <span class="zoom-content photo-container" ng-click="zoomClose()"><img hm-pinchin="pinchIn" hm-pinchout="pinchOut" ng-src="{{zoomPictureSrc}}" /></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wrapped it in a single controller.  If you need to maintain separate controllers for whatever reason, you will need to find a way to share data between them.  Like with a service or factory.